# Does Android run a modified Java machine?

Tags: java, android, jvm

I've always thought the JVM has been pretty "bloated up" since EE versions, but now seems like Android devices are pretty fast (as mobile devices of course)

Has the Android java machine been modified by Google? What has been changed?

I can't find any information about this

Comment: Your premisses are pretty dubious. I doubt J2EE has had any impact on the JVM itself at all actually, except maybe motivating the -server version, and the JVM certainly hasn't been getting any slower either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. It uses the [Dalvik VM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29).

Comment: Thank you! I'll mark this as answer as soon as the system lets me

Comment: Consider adding a little more "meat" to answers -- e.g. a brief snippet of why/how it is different (there are a few choice excerpts available in the linked article that would summarize it nicely).